# Modifying video rendering in Surface View in AOSP

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-source, android-mediacodec, surface

I built my own AOSP and I need to modify video frames in SurfaceView - e.g. add brightness or change the color scheme. I tried to dig in GraphicBuffer, MediaCodec and Surface side and eventually didn't get place where I can modify video stream. Maybe these movements take place in cpp files.

I know that it is pretty complicated thing. But maybe someone can give me some hints where I should dig or give references or explanations. Any hints are appreciated, thanks.